# Is there a cleaner way for passing a bunch of generics?

Tags: rust

I have this function with two generic parameters and I will have to add more of them.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
fn handle_connection<Reqparser: traits::Reqparser<Stream = Stream>, Responder: traits::Responder>(mut stream: Stream) {...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`where` clause](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/where.html) when an inline generic parameter list gets unwieldy:

```
fn handle_connection<Reqparser, Responder>(mut stream: Stream)
where
    Reqparser: traits::Reqparser<Stream = Stream>,
    Responder: traits::Responder,
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know about the where clause, I thought there might be a better way. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Szegoo how do you envision a cleaner way than that?

Comment: @Dominic I thought maybe you could define the generics outside the function interface (something like the type in traits) into some sort of a group, and then reference that in the function interface. It was just a thought nothing more :D.

Comment: @Szegoo, You can group the generic bounds on an impl block for a struct or trait